# Can a son perform amavasya tarpanam in place of his sick father?

Tags: dharma, practice, dharma-shastras, yajna, amavasya

Doing *tarpanam* (water libations) on the day of Amavasya is a well-known fact. My father was doing it very sincerely on all Amavasyas.

But now, since he became very old and has health issues, he is not able to do it.  My question is, can I do it in place of my father?

I know that if one's father is alive, one should not do *tarpanam*. But in this case, the father is not able to do it for health reasons.

Comment: I'd check with a local "Vadhiyar" (priest) or call up Kanchi Sankar mutt and get an answer. Let's see if you get a response.

Comment: Somewhat related the following answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38703/4732

Comment: I have read that one can do the Samvatsara shrAddha karma, that is the yearly death anniversary shrAddha. So, I think you could do the same. The mantras are almost the same, but I think you need to omit one generation of pitrus (your father) in the mantras. That is, you must give tarpanams for only your grandfather (in case in he is no more) and great grandfather and great great grandfather. So , I think they become your Vasu, rudra an aditya oblations